# How can multiple clients access single remote desktop?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access

Is there any way in which multiple clients can access a single remote desktop?

In case of XRDP, client can access a single remote host. But i want multiple clients to access a single remote host.

If that is possible, then can those client can have their independent sessions?
Here for example, if one client uses software like MS Word on the host, then other client which is using same or any other software, should not interfere each other.

Is this possible?

Comment: And the remote host is Linux or Windows? Because you mentioned MS Word, I suppose that the remote host is Windows. In that case, the question is off-topic here. You should ask on Windows forums how to configure terminal services on a Windows host so that multiple simultaneous logins are possible.
As far as I know it is possible only on server versions of Windows. However, it is definitely possible, I have used such setups.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand you correctly, yes.

There's something called x2go. Which is basically something simuler to citrix.

This should get you started: 
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/install-x2go-server-and-client-on-ubuntu-15-04-vivid-vervet.html

Project HP: http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/start

NB:It does not support the Unity Desktop.

Comment: Actually, xrdp does nor support unity, is not something related to x2go :)

Comment: Oh thank you, I dont know the project in depth. I've just used it from time to time :). I dont know what xrdp is so i would not be able to explain it. I just know unity is not supported :).

Comment: RDP is a protocol of remote desktop. For using it on ubuntu you need to install another desktop, thats why I always use Lubuntu for remote enviroments, xfce desktop comes already installed.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but how is this connected to x2go? x2go creates a locale Xserver, does it use the rdp protocol?

Comment: XRDP is the protocol of remote desktop, and x2go the xserver, how you say. xrdp works on the remote desktop escenarios, no matter what server or client you use.